# Which is not a level of architecture?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I was taking up a mock architectural test where I encounter a question

```
Which of the following is not a level of architecture:

    a) Design Patterns
    b) Requirements Analysis
    c) Application Architecture
    d) Enterprise Architecture
    e) Application Framework
```

I didnot understand what the question is saying? Any thought?

Thanks

Comment: This question is asking "did you read your professor's lecture notes"?

Comment: One of those is a human-oriented _process_ and the others are all possible to spot in _code_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requirements Analysis** finds out **what** feature the software should implement.

**architecture** is the big picture of **how** this is implemented - it is part of the design.

**b** is the only point that not concerned with a **how** question.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter implies, at some point the lecturer gave a list of "levels of architecture", and you're expected to cough them up here. If I had to guess, I'd say "b", requirements analysis, is the odd one out: it is a process, while all the others are aspects of software implementation or design

Comment: in the 4+1 view of architecture, requirements are the +1.